# Update multiple divs with AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I'm trying to update many divs within an html table.
I grabbed an example code from https://www.easy-coding.de/wiki/Entry/64-Mehrere-DIV-Container-mit-AJAX-aktualisieren/ and in general it is working as it should.

Every div, which needs to be updated has a unique id (e.g. "s-1", "s-2", "s-3", ...) and contains the following script snippet:

```
<div id="s-<?php echo $contact_array_row['id']; ?>">initial content</div><script type="text/javascript">up.push('s-<?php echo $contact_array_row['id']; ?>');</script>
```

This is my modified refresh java script:

```
/**
 * xxx [..] by http://www.easy-coding.de
 * 
 * @param url
 * @param poll      
 */
function UpdateManyDivs(url, poll, tab) {
    this.url = url;
    this.poll = poll ? poll : 750;
    this.list = [];
    this.timer = null;
    this.tab = tab;

    /**
     * adds elem
     * @param   id      string as id
     */
    this.push = function(id) {
        this.list.push(id);
    };

    /**
     * sends single request
     * @param loop  boolean     
     */
    this.fire = function(loop) {
        ajaxPost(this.url + '?' +this.list.join('&'), 'seed='+ new Date().getTime() + '&tab=' + tab, function(up) {
            return function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    if(loop) {
                        // start timer
                        up.start();
                    }

                    var data = eval('(' + this.responseText + ')');
                    for(var key in data) {
                        document.getElementById(key).innerHTML = data[key];
                    }
                }
            };
        }(this));
    };

    /**
     * stops auto updater
     */
    this.stop = function() {
        window.clearTimeout(this.timer);
    };

    /**
     * starts auto updater
     */
    this.start = function() {
        this.timer = window.setTimeout(function(up) {
            return function() {
                up.fire(true);
            };
        }(this), this.poll);
    };

}
```

It is called with the following one-liner:

```
var up = new UpdateManyDivs('include/callback.php', 1000, event_id);
```

The problem is, that most of the data is written in the $_GET variable.
If the table containing the divs is too big, it isn't working anymore.
I would like to use the $_POST variable instead, and therefore changed the following line:

```
ajaxPost(this.url + '?' +this.list.join('&'), 'seed='+ new Date().getTime() + '&tab=' + tab, function(up) {
```

...to this one:

```
ajaxPost(this.url, '?' +this.list.join('&') + '&seed='+ new Date().getTime() + '&tab=' + tab, function(up) {
```

In my callback PHP script I changed the following foreach loop:

```
foreach(array_keys($_GET) as $identifier) {
    $identifier_array = explode("-", $identifier);
    $data[$identifier] = getStatusMYSQL($identifier_array[1],$identifier_array[0],$_POST['tab']);
}
```

...to this one:

```
foreach(array_keys($_POST) as $identifier) {
    $identifier_array = explode("-", $identifier);
    $data[$identifier] = getStatusMYSQL($identifier_array[1],$identifier_array[0],$_POST['tab']);
}
```

Unfortunately this isn't working and after several hours trying to fix it, I'm out of ideas.

Is there anything, I'm missing?

Thanks,
relkai

Comment: I'm fairly sure removing a single ampersand isn't going to make the function change from get to post.

Comment: Because the "tab" variable is already written into $_POST, I thought it would be possible to move the other data to it, too. But obviously you are right. Unfortunately my JavaScript knowledge isn't really good, and I can't find a way to switch it to $_POST instead.